# how to server html pages with play

Tags: html, scala, playframework

Hi I would like to serve my index.html page from the controller. and i do not want it to be a view, i want it to be a pure html file i have no need for plays template engine.

Consider the following:

Route: `GET /   controllers.MainApp.index`

And the route implementation is:

> ```
> def index = Action { implicit request =>
>    if (AuthenticatedAction.isAuthenticated) {
>       Ok(controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/", file="index.html"))     
>     }    
>      else Redirect(controllers.routes.Authentication.login())  }
> ```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot write an instance of play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]]
```

Is there any way to serve an html page like that?

A possible solution is to do something like that:

route: `GET  /*file   controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)`

and then return from the controller:

```
Redirect("/index.html")
```

Which gives me a url path which i don't want:

```
http://localhost:9000/index.html#/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is to return

```
controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/", file="index.html")
```

rather than

```
Ok(controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/", file="index.html"))
```

The at method already returns a Result, so you don't need to use Ok here.